# How i fixed this error in android studio

Tags: android

how i fixed this error in android studio
Error:Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits 
 ([a-z0-9_.])
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Ttanslation\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\TRAN2.png: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Comment: you have to be more specific. provide code samples.

Answer (score 2):

You rename your file to

```
tran2.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error message it is clearly written what mistake you have done.

> Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

In android, Resource files and folders name

- Can't contain uppercase letter.
- Can't contain digit in the beginning.
- Can have only underscore as special character.

And in your case you used uppercase in the name, So simply change the file name TRAN2.png to something else that accepts the rule.